# How to see file exit in bash

Tags: bash

I am getting syntax error with (( )) brackets,

```
         read  -p "enter the file name: " file

        if  ((  -e   "$file"  ))
        then
         echo  " $file  exit"
        else
        echo  " $file  not exit "
         fi
```

Comment: `(( ))` is only for math. `[[ ]]` is the general extended test syntax.

Comment: `if [ -f "$file" ]`